# White space at the bottom of the page on the right side, the left is correctly background color filled

Tags: html, css

My apology, if I am not doing this (updating my original) correctly.

I stripped the code and pin pointed the statements that would cause the white space at the bottom of the "short list" side of the page.
Recap from previous post - here's the DIV in the page layout:
* div-1 The title aka titleFrame [ This is static ]
* div-2 The menu aka menu [ This is static ]
* div-3 The main aka mainFrame [ Dynamic content area ]

Objective: When a menu item is clicked, mainFrame.innerHTML content is updated.

Understanding the problem: The mainFrame DIV may contain two child DIVs, refer to the following set of codes for the discussion:
*** Set A: This set does not have a parent DIV

```
<div id="freewareLeft"> Left list </div>
<div id="freewareRight"> Right list </div>
```

*** Set B: This set has a parent DIV, with or without an ID name [ ie. div instead of div id="mainFrame" ]

```
<div id="mainFrame" style="line-height: 20px;">
   <div id="freewareLeft"> ... </div>
   <div id="freewareRight"> ... </div>
</div>
```

*** Set C: This is the desired code because of the flexibility

...

Set A: There is no problem with this set of code. Sizing does not produce any white space on the short list side.
Set B: If freeLeft and freeRight has a parent DIV (with or without an ID), the white space on the short list side shows up.
Set C: This is the desired set of code (one DIV) because mainFrame.innerHTML could be updated with one content or a split screen (two) contents with Left and Right DIV. Note: It work if the update does not contain child DIVs.

Here's the stripped down code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <style>
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 24px;
    }

    .parent{
        display: flex;
    }

    #titleFrame { /* Welcome to the CyberPlaypen */
      position: fixed; 
      top: 0; left: 0; 
      height: 30px; line-height: 30px; width: 100%;
      font-weight: bold;
      overflow: hidden; /* Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
      text-align: center; 
      color: white; background: navy;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    #menu {
      min-width: 1000px;
      position: fixed;
      margin-top: 30px;
      height: 24px;
      line-height: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #0000FF;
      /* opacity: 0.6; */
      z-index: 2;
    }

    #menu a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      width: 80px; /*added */
      display: block;
    }

    #menu a:hover {
      background-color: green;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      /* border-radius: 6px; */
    }

    #mainFrame {
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;
      top: 54px;
      margin-left: 0px; /* was 20px */
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      /* tried min-height: 100vh; same result */
      z-index: 1;
    }

    #freewareLeft {

      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      width: 216px; 
      min-height: 100vh;
      border-right: 1px solid white;
    }

    #freewareLeft * {
      margin-left: 15px;
    }


    #freewareRight {

      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      width: calc(100% - 217px); 
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="titleFrame">
      Welcome to CyberPlaypen
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <a style="width: 80px;" href="#" onclick="mouseBrowseReset(); codeInjector('mainFrame','Software/softFreeware.txt');">Freeware</a>
    </div>

<!-- put <div id="mainFrame"> here to see the problem, also try with a blank <div> and it's worse -->
    <div id="freewareLeft">
      <br />Test
      <br />Test <!-- Repeat this x times - make one list shorter -->
      <br />Test
    </div>
    <div id="freewareRight">
      <br />Test
      <br />Test <!-- Repeat this x times - make one list shorter -->
      <br />Test
    </div> 
<!-- put closing </div> if testing with <div id="mainFrame"> or blank </div> -->

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving height as 100vh and after scroll you actually need height as 100% of parent and your all 3 divs sits directly inside the body. Here is the solution.
Add a parent div and set style as `display: flex;`

In your html

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
        <div id="titleFrame">
            Welcome to CyberPlaypen
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
..... other html
</table>
        </div>
        <div id="freewareRight">
            <img src onerror="codeInjector('freewareRight','./Default.txt');">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in your styles

```
.parent{
        display: flex;
    }
```

EDIT:
Wrap the content of left/right div in a no-name div.The code after innerHTML is modified with XMLHttpRequest() looks like this: [body] [div mainFrame] [div left][div]content[/div][/div] [div right][div]content[/div/[/div] [ /div] [/body]

Comment: I plugged your suggested code into the posted code snippet and it worked. I plugged the same statements into the full code and had the same issue. As time permit, I will start from a simple baseline and rebuild the codes to see where the problem starts to show. In my full code testing,I did notice that if I vertical resized slowly the full code (with or without your recommendation), the white-space only appeared in the right div after the scrollbar is triggered by the left side div (the bottom edge of the window moved into the left side content).

Comment: The suggested .parent code work for the simplified snippet but did not work for my particular situation. After further testing, I discovered (Referencing the structure of the content boxes in the original post). The code worked if the content of the FreeRight (FR) and FreeLeft (FL) are static (embedded code). The code did not work if the FR and FL are dynamically injected via "document.getElementById(thisTarget).innerHTML=location;". It exhibited the symptom: Whichever side (FR or FL) has the shorter list, white space showed below when the browser window is resized to less than the long list.

Comment: @Gnart can you share a sample codepen or fiddle may be?

Comment: I will strip and create a working skeleton to post at one of the above sites. The semester is ending. It's busy time so it will take a few days before I could get to it.

Comment: fiddle and codepen seems to be a playgrounds, so I updated my original post. My apology if I shouldn't have done this. Just let me know the proper procedure for posting follow-ups.  The new post is cleaner and I was able to target the code that caused the error.

Comment: Here's the link to fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gnart/xoy0uc7v/2/)
The code has the parent div (mainFrame with or without an ID); Thus it shows white spaces at the bottom of the short list (right side). Remove the parent div and no white spaces.

Comment: @Gnart The solution that gave it to you still valid, I have added display : flex in mainframe and it is working fine.  #mainFrame {
          position: relative;
          overflow: auto;
          top: 54px;
          margin-left: 0px; /* was 20px */
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          /* tried min-height: 100vh; same result */
          z-index: 1;
          display: flex;
        }

Comment: There is no question that your solution work in the code with the Left/Right div coded inline as children of mainFrame div in the html body. When I pulled the LeftRight div out and use onclick XMLHttpRequest() to update the mainFrame div innerHTM with LeftRight div [production version] with flex, the content is no longer aligned. Anyway, I am working on realigning the content and will update on issues. It's fix one thing and break so many others.

Comment: The .parent flex as suggested worked on the simple page. When I implement to the production code, all kind of errors started to appeared. After some trials and errors, I got it to work. The only place where it would work was to put flex in the mainFrame div. It hosts the left/right div. Then wrap the content of left/right div in a no-name div. Not sure why the blank div is needed. The code (in memory) after innerHTML is modified with XMLHttpRequest() looks like this: 
[body]
  [div mainFrame]
    [div left][div]content[/div][/div]
    [div right][div]content[/div/[/div]
  [ /div]
[/body]